# Argmax - all maximizer positions

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Generally the Argmax function returns one position, where a function is maximized.
Is there a easy way to obtain a list of rules for all maximizer points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f[x_] = LaguerreL[6, x];

ArgMax[{f[x], 0 < x < 10}, x] // N

(* 8.39907 *)
```

The maxima occur where the derivative is zero and the second derivative is negative.

```
(argMax = Solve[{f'[x] == 0, f''[x] < 0}, x, Reals]) // N

(* {{x -> 2.11297}, {x -> 8.39907}} *)

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[{x, f[x]} /. argMax]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!